# What would I have to do to make the text and the radio buttons shown in this css code properly line up with each other?

Tags: css

If you try and type text in an h1 segment in html with an input type of radio, the text and the button doesn't line up.  Please help out a coding newbie with this problem, and have a good day :)

```
input[type='radio'] {
margin: 0;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
filter: brightness(10%);
}
body {
text-align: center;
}
h1 {
font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: can you give an example what you mean

Comment: Without your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML your CSS is meaningless due to a lack of context.

Answer (score 0):

there is not html provided, so i assume there are only radio and h1 in the body.

```
input[type='radio'] {
   margin: 0;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   filter: brightness(10%);
   vertical-align: middle; /*add this*/
}
h1{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```